R kabelextra error while saving table as png or pdf
Trying to save a table I generated with kable as a png or pdf file.  Using the example code in the documentation for save_kable
  kable_styling("striped") %>%
  row_spec(1, color = "red") %>%
  save_kable("test.pdf")```

I receive the error
>Error in `with_random_port()`:
! Cannot find an available port. Please try again.
Caused by error in `startup()`:
! Failed to start chrome. Error: 
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.


Could anyone help?
Using package kableextra version 1.4.0 on Windows 11 with R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt)" and RStudio 2024.04.2 Build 764


That error is coming from chromote, which recently had problems with new versions of Chrome.  I think they were fixed, so updating your packages should help.  See https://github.com/rstudio/chromote/issues/170 .

The Chromote library update may help with the png and not the pdf, so try both after up date.

Works thank you.
However after running the mtcars example in the kabel_save documentation I receive the error Error: rsession-utf8.exe: GeometryDoesNotContainImage.  I find that image "test.,png" exists but is empty.  Any suggestions?  Have updated webshot2 and magick packages.
